# How to build restful DELETE URL with many parameters?

Tags: java, resteasy, restful-url

I create a restful DELETE service, for example, the URL is

```
http://localhost/book/10,
```

use DELETE method to send this request, but I need to record this operation by which user, so I need to send an operatorId parameter with that DELETE method request. How to build this delete url?

```
http://localhost/book/10?operatorId=10
```

or

```
http://localhost/book/10/operator-id/10
```

or other url.

Can you help me?

Comment: Hi @Liu, Can you clarify what you need help with?  Is it which format to use, how to build it the url, or if this is even a good idea (it's not).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't want just anyone deleting, so you can just check the cookie or basic auth credentials sent along with the request.

Plus, a RESTful DELETE is supposed to be idempotent, meaning that nothing changes when the same call is made. If you're mucking with the database, it's no longer a valid contract between the client and the server.